# Formulate a relation $R$ between $2$ sets $A$ and $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $A$ and $B$ be $2$ sets of real numbers.
How can I formulate the following entence, in mathematical terms, not plain english.

> IF At least one Element $x$ of $A$ is equal to one element $y$ of $B$
>   then It's raining else sunny.

Comment: Here you are defining $A=R$ and $B=R$. That is probably not your intention.

Comment: I am? not of course not it's not my intention. should remove this relation R?

Comment: you are saying: $A=\left\{ x\mid x\in R\right\} $ wich means exactly the same as
$A=R$

Comment: sheesh That's not what I want

Comment: Should remove this Relation? Do you think it is complicating more than it is helping? Do u understand what i meanr?

Comment: By the way: a relation $R$ between $A$ and $B$ is by definition a subset of $A\times B$ to answer your last question.

Comment: Damn it my mistake u confused R with the real numbers

Comment: Is it still wrong drhab?

Comment: You are now saying that $A=\mathbb{R}=B$. Is that what you want? In that case one speak of a relation on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @drhab What I want to say is that: If at least one element x of A is equal to at least one element y of B then it's sunny else it's rainy. Forget The relation i'll rephrase the stupid question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11906/discussion-between-hani-gotc-and-drhab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left[\exists x\in A\exists y\in B\; x=y\Rightarrow\text{it is sunny}\right]\wedge\left[\forall x\in A\forall y\in B\; x\neq y\Rightarrow\text{it is rainy}\right]$

Comment: That's it!! Thank you so much!!!